# Can I run Ubuntu from a from a pen drive?

Tags: installation, usb, cd

I was thinking if I can run Ubuntu from a pen drive, like rather than have it run from a CD would it be possible to run it from a pen drive...

Answer (score 1):

I run from flash drives all the time. I carry a half dozen flavors of linux with me in my backpack.

There are great instructions on the ubuntu website. Install iso to flash drive according to your current OS.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: yes, but do you know where i can get instructions to set the whole thing up on my flash drive...? please

Comment: @user209560 Try [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). If you are currently using ubuntu, you can get it by `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`. I think the flash drive cannot have ntfs or FAT* file systems. If you have trouble with unetbootin not recognizing your flash drive just reformat it to ext4 (using gparted or something similar) first.